# Build an SQL string from a group of OptionGroups

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Im trying to get my head around this and the more I do, the more of a maze im creating in my head.

**Set the scene:**
I have 12 Option Groups. Each with Yes/No radio buttons in them. When a user clicks options I want to store the information in a function (functions are new to me). I then want to execute some SQL each time they select an option this will return X amount of records which is displayed in a label.

Ive tried a few things, but this is what I have right now.

**Current Code:**

```
Function getValues(grp As OptionGroup)

Select Case grp.Value 'Option group name me.liveInUK
    Case 1
        OptionValue = "columnName = Yes"
    Case 2
        OptionValue = "columnName = No"
End Select


Select Case grp.Value 'Option group name me.drivingLicence 
    Case 1
        OptionValue = OptionValue & "columnName2 = Yes"
    Case 2
        OptionValue = OptionValue & "columnName2 = No"
End Select

sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE OptionValue"

rs.MoveFirst
profileAccountsValueabel.Caption = rs.Fields
  
Set rs = Nothing

End Function
```

I understand this wont actually run - What I want to try and understand is how each time a radio button is clicked the correct values get updated for all 12 option groups.

Any guidance in the right direction is much appreciated

Comment: You would normally either have controls bound to fields in a table, or else deal with values all at once often when a command button is clicked. What you are trying to do makes no sense.

Comment: You have 12 yes/no fields? Bind OptionGroup frame to field if you want to save selection. Instead of yes or no, wouldn't it be more informative to have a DateIssued for driving license? As well as LastYearInUK? Etc. If you don't want to save these values in table, just use as filter criteria, for ideas on how to build criteria from multiple controls, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. You reference a recordset variable but do not show declaring nor setting it. Don't need recordset just to get a count of table records - use DCount() domain aggregate function.